# How do I save annotations?

Tags: swift, gps, annotations, mapkit

I have my code so it puts an annotation on the map each time the user clicks a button, but when the user closes out of the app, the annotation disappears. How do I make it so the annotations stays on the map even when the user closes the app? Below is my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class UpdateCar: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

@IBOutlet weak var lblLocation: UILabel!

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

var myPosition = CLLocationCoordinate2D()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation!, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation!) {

    println("Updating Car Location \(newLocation.coordinate.latitude) , \(newLocation.coordinate.longitude) ")

    myPosition = newLocation.coordinate

    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    lblLocation.text = "\(newLocation.coordinate.latitude) , \(newLocation.coordinate.longitude)"
}

@IBAction func findUserLocationAndDropPin(sender: UIButton) {
    var userLocationCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude)
    var pinForUserLocation = MKPointAnnotation()
    pinForUserLocation.coordinate = userLocationCoordinates
    mapView.addAnnotation(pinForUserLocation)
    mapView.showAnnotations([pinForUserLocation], animated: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: Your question is also answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464740/how-to-save-pin-annotation-once-app-is-closed-swift

Answer (score 1):

```
//when I need to save for example, the last date on which the user login my app will use the setObject function, this will save a value ("10/05/2015") in the "lastlogin" key
var lastLogin = "10/05/2015"
NSUserDefaults.standarUserDefaults().setObject(lastLogin, forkey: "lastLogin")
//And when I need to retrieve the stored value in the "lastlogin" key which I use is "objectForKey" function
NSUserDefaults.standarUserDefaults().objectForKey("lastLogin")
```

see following link:
    https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setObject:forKey:

Comment: [Picture](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1flM04508p8Tbee0XEcRDSDUsD3XskYXhAT8eAqcDPjU/edit?usp=sharing)  The link shoes you an error I'm getting. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is simple setObject function where you want save the value and objectForKey where you want retrieve the value saved

Comment: So, I'm having troubles. I think all my code is correct according to what you have but it still won't save any annotations. [Here is my code](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/108obwcTBaQNWdMYWxKR9MGFDXFVBlBKMYSfQ2ZNs6ok/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

You have to save it in a persistent store.

Few options:

- [CoreData](http://www.raywenderlich.com/85578/first-core-data-app-using-swift), the native way of saving data, recommended, not too easy
- [NSUserDefaults](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-nsuserdefaults--mobile-6039), usually thought for small stuff, also native, not recommended, very easy though
- Another API for managing a persistent store like [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) (similar to CoreData, a little easier but not native)

Comment: It isn't a large amount of data, it's only one annotation.

Comment: What kind of code do I need to us NSUserDefaults, I checked out the link, but it is an outdated source.

Comment: @GlacierDevelopments just look at the other answer