# How to save Pin Annotation once app is closed (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, nsuserdefaults

Currently, my app pins a location and that location is stores like so:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    // Find location of user
    var userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as! CLLocation
    var latitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
    var longitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude
    var latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
    var longDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
    var span: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, longDelta)
    var location:MKUserLocation = currentLocation;
    var region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location.coordinate, span)
    var coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
    carInitialLocation = userLocation;
    locationsDefaults.append(carInitialLocation);
    carInitialCoordinate = coordinate;

    self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true);
}
```

where locationsDefaults is the array where I store the location of the pin.

I would like to use NSUserdefaults, but i'm not really sure how i'd do that as it doesn't except non NS data. A guideline/structure in swift would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What results / errors do you get? What is the expected result?

Comment: Well, i'm trying to use NSuserdefaults, but a type of CLLocation will not be stored into the NSuserDefaults..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save NSData to NSUserDefaults. So all you need is to convert your CLLocation object to NSData using [NSKeyedArchiver](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/index.html) method [archivedDataWithRootObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSKeyedArchiver/archivedDataWithRootObject:) as follow:

```
// saving your CLLocation object
let locationData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(carInitialLocation)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(locationData, forKey: "locationData")

// loading it
if let loadedData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dataForKey("locationData") {
    if let loadedLocation = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(loadedData) as? CLLocation {
        println(loadedLocation.coordinate.latitude)
        println(loadedLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So would this be all inside of viewdidload method?

Comment: You can place the save part anywhere you have access to your location object. An you can load it when viewdidload if you want

Comment: I have a trash option that allows the user to delete their selected pin. So in that button's action, I would just ?

Comment: @VarunVarahabotla feel free to open another question and post the related code there. I will be glad to help you there if I can

Comment: I can only post once every 90 minutes, so I will update this question to the question i have. please check the updated question

Comment: @VarunVarahabotla if you edit your question my answer won't make any sense. You should respect the time limit. It is there for a reason. once you get enough reputation you probably will be able to post as many questions as you want. you should roll back your edit and open a new question once they allow you to.

Comment: Ok I rolled it back. Here is the link to the new question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31465870/storing-cllocation-and-keeping-annotation